# Win32api passing struct to create thread

Tags: c, winapi, createthread

i'm trying to get this struct into my thread, however i'm getting trash in it.

struct i'm using:

```
typedef struct {
    HWND hWnd;
    int cntrlid;
    TCHAR text[BUFF];
}parametros;
```

in the message switch i have the case to control a button witch starts the thread:

```
    case IDC_TAB_A:
        threaddata.hWnd=hWnd;
        threaddata.cntrlid=IDC_TAB_A;
        _tcscpy(threaddata.text, _T("Carregou A"));
        hThreadsender=CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) ThreadSenderProc, (LPVOID) &threaddata, 0, NULL);

        break;
```

and the function to handle the thread i got:

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadSenderProc(LPVOID param){

    parametros temp=*((parametros *)param);
    EnviaLetra(temp.hWnd, temp.text,temp.cntrlid);

    return 0;
}
```

something must be wrong, but i cant get what it is, can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!
(sorry bad english!)

Comment: my only problem was that i wasnt looking at the obvious error, the structure i was using was being destroyed.

Comment: A write breakpoint would have shown why the value was changing unexpectedly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your structure is destroyed before the thread can access it. Either use an event to synchronize, or allocate your structure dynamically.

PS: Remove that hideous `(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)` cast. If you declare your function correctly, you won't need it. Function pointer casts are to ban unless you know exactly what you're doing and why.
Oh, and the `(LPVOID)` cast is useless too.

Comment: its the copy paste:P this is a uni homework so i was just copying class examples, going to mallock that struct and check what happens
thanks for your answer

Comment: god, mate, i love you, i puled so mutch hair today, after 4 pomodoros that problem happened, 5 later here we hare, thanks!

Comment: @RogerMartins Please accept the answer. FWIW, using heap allocation is the right solution here. Using an event to sync is heavy duty and costs more. It's a poor solution. Heap allocation is the way to go. And yes, stop all that nasty casting!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i think i accepted it now, new to posting here, usualy i lurk